# Computing a polynomial with function call in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that relies on a function call to compute 3x^5+2x^4-5x^3-x^2+7x-6. However, it keeps returning the value of 0 for my function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int x, int polynomial)
{
polynomial = (3 * x * x * x * x * x) + (2 * x * x * x * x) - (5 * x * x * x) - (2 * x * x) + (7 * x) - 6;
return polynomial; 
}

int main(void)
{
int x, polynomial;

printf("The program will compute the following polynomial: \n");
printf("3x^5 + 2x^4 - 5x^3 - x^2 + 7x - 6 \n");
printf("Please enter a value for x: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

function(x, polynomial);

return 0;
```

}

Why is it doing this? How can I return the value from the function into the main?

Comment: I got it to work correctly by assigning a variable to the function. Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use built-in Math functions? It would look less confusing

Answer (score 3):

Assign the value of a variable to what the function called `function` returns:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int function(int x)
{
    polynomial = (3 * x * x * x * x * x) + (2 * x * x * x * x) - (5 * x * x * x) - (2 * x * x) + (7 * x) - 6;
    return polynomial; 
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, result;

    printf("The program will compute the following polynomial: \n");
    printf("3x^5 + 2x^4 - 5x^3 - x^2 + 7x - 6 \n");
    printf("Please enter a value for x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    result = function(x);

    /* do something with result, like print it */

    return 0;
}
```

(Ideally, you would not call a function `function` but something else.)

If you're really trying to modify a dereferenced pointer, then you need to make a few changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int x, int* polynomial)
{
    *polynomial = (3 * x * x * x * x * x) + (2 * x * x * x * x) - (5 * x * x * x) - (2 * x * x) + (7 * x) - 6;
}

int main(void)
{
    int x, result;

    printf("The program will compute the following polynomial: \n");
    printf("3x^5 + 2x^4 - 5x^3 - x^2 + 7x - 6 \n");
    printf("Please enter a value for x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    function(x, &result);

    /* do something with result, like print it */

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, `function` is a `void` and so does not return anything. You pass it the value `x` and the memory address of `result`. That memory address gets dereferenced in `function`, and then the dereferenced address can have its value set as whatever `polynomial` ends up being.

After leaving `function` and going back to `main`, the value of `result` contains the calculation performed in `function`.